# Select not null columns dynamically from a table to join with other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have table1 as below

```
Col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
1    a    b    c    d     4
1    a    b    f    g     4
2    a    i    j    k     5
2    l    m    n    o     4
3    l    m    n    o     4
3    p    q    q    s     6
3    t    u    v    w     7
```

I have table2 as below

```
RowNumber col1 col2    col3  col4  col5  count_of_records
1           1    a     null  null  null   2
2           2    a     i     null  null   1
3           3    null  null  null  null   3
```

We have to delete the records from table1 using records from table2.
Example, for first row in table2, we have to join it with table1 and get the count of records in table1. here only two columns are joined as only those two are not null values in table2 in first record.
query will be

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM table1
inner join table2
on table1.col1 = table2.col1
and table1.col2 = table2.col2
where rownumber =1
output : 2
```

if this count matches with count_of_records in table2 we have to delete this record. In this case as count is matching we need to generate one delete query

```
DELETE FROM table1
inner join table2
on table1.col1 = table2.col1
and table1.col2 = table2.col2
```

Please suggest a way to achieve this dynamically for each row in table2. We can do it either using SQL or SSIS.

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev please don't ask the OP to provide ther DDL and DML on an external site. If they want to provide it, it should be in teh question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will give you what you are looking for. If you are on SQL Server 2016 or greater, you can replace the `IF OBJECT_ID()` checks with `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS`.

The trick is in the join between the two tables, which has null checks for each one. If the column is null, it ignores the join. I assumed col1 was always equal since it appeared that way in your metadata. If not, it can be modified to match the other join predicates.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#table1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #table1
CREATE TABLE #table1
(
    col1 INT
    , col2 CHAR(1)
    , col3 CHAR(1)
    , col4 CHAR(1)
    , col5 CHAR(1)
    , col6 INT
)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#table2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #table2
CREATE TABLE #table2
(
    RowNumber INT
    , col1 INT
    , col2 CHAR(1)
    , col3 CHAR(1)
    , col4 CHAR(1)
    , col5 CHAR(1)
    , count_of_records INT
)

INSERT INTO #table1 (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6) VALUES
    (1, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 4),
    (1, 'a', 'b', 'f', 'g', 4),
    (2, 'a', 'i', 'j', 'k', 5),
    (2, 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 4),
    (3, 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 4),
    (3, 'p', 'q', 'q', 's', 6),
    (3, 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 7)

INSERT INTO #table2 (RowNumber, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, count_of_records) VALUES
    (1, 1, 'a', null, null, null, 2),
    (2, 2, 'a', 'i', null, null, 1),
    (3, 3, null, null, null, null, 3)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#counts') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #counts
CREATE TABLE #counts
(
    RowNumber INT
    , original_count INT
    , record_count INT
)

INSERT INTO #counts (RowNumber, original_count, record_count)
SELECT
    RowNumber
    , count_of_records
    , COUNT(*) AS record_count
FROM
    #table2 t2
    INNER JOIN #table1 t1
        ON t2.col1 = t1.col1
        AND (t2.col2 IS NULL OR t2.col2 = t1.col2)
        AND (t2.col3 IS NULL OR t2.col3 = t1.col3)
        AND (t2.col4 IS NULL OR t2.col4 = t1.col4)
        AND (t2.col5 IS NULL OR t2.col5 = t1.col5)
GROUP BY
    RowNumber
    , count_of_records

DELETE t1
FROM
    #table1 t1
    INNER JOIN #counts c
        ON t1.Col1 = c.RowNumber
        AND c.original_count = c.record_count

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #table1
```